# Unable to load template from VS2017 to VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a Vsix Template Project/Package in VS2017 to Deploy the template on Different Visual Studio Version. After Installing Package using Wix Toolset that template should be Visible on VS 2015 , VS 2017 and VS 2019 in New Project Window.

When i Install the package from Wix ToolSet, the Template is Visible for VS2015 and VS 2017(Enterprise), but not showing on VS2019 (When Open VS2019 File->New->Project(New Project Window)). I am unable to see the template.

See below Screen Shot for VS2017 where I can be able to see The template.

[image]

But i cannot see the same for VS 2019 Version. See Below ScreenShot for VS2019. I have made necessary changes to Visible template for VS2019.
Am I missing any settings for VS2019. Please help.

[image]

Thanks for your time.